# applicationDidFinishLaunching not getting called

Tags: xcode15, macos-sonoma

In my macOS AppDelegate.swift code, I can set a breakpoint at the top of func applicationDidFinishLaunching() but it never gets hit. Worked fine in Xcode 14.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    print("in applicationDidFinishLaunching" )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s deprecated method.

> Use application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) instead.

Comment: Thank for Fedy for your response. If it's deprecated, shouldn't it still work, just with a compile warning?

All of the examples I can find indicate this is only for iOS applications, not macOS. Do you know if this is the case?

This is what I have now and it's still not being called:

    func application(application: NSApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
        print("in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" )
        return true;
    }

Comment: I did some more research, applicationDidFinishLaunching is deprecated with UIKit (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623053-applicationdidfinishlaunching) but is not with AppKit (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428385-applicationdidfinishlaunching)